# Getting 401 from Netsuite REST API

Tags: postman, netsuite, http-status-code-401

I'm following this tutorial here to attempt to authenticate using [Token Based Authentication with Netsuite:](https://blogs.oracle.com/integration/post/oracle-integration-connecting-to-netsuite-using-token-based-authentication#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Setup%20in%20NetSuite,authentication%20with%20RESTlets%2C%20If%20it)

through postman using Netsuite's Postman environment, but I continue to receive "401 Invalid login attempt".

When I check the Login Audit Trail, I see that there is no role being assigned to my authentication attempts -- it's just blank. To me, this indicates that the token is not properly assigned to the User/Role, but I've walked through the directions several times and everything appears to be setup properly.

I've seen other similar posts about this, but those seem to boil down to the Netsuite Account ID formatting. However, my Netsuite Account ID is all numbers, so I don't think this is a factor.

Comment: follow this tutorial until step 5.  https://morrisdev.medium.com/netsuite-token-based-authentication-tba-342c7df56386

Answer (score 4):

This should work fine assuming you have created an integration and an access token.  Configure Oauth 1.0 in postman with the following fields filled out correctly:

- signature method (should be `HMAC-256`)
- consumer key (from the integration you created in netsuite)
- consumer secret (from the integration you created in netsuite)
- access token (from the access token created in netsuite)
- token secret (from the access token created in netsuite)
- realm (your account id, if using a sandbox, make sure the realm looks like `1234567_SB1`, with an `_` and not a `-`)

You won't be able to complete TBA using postman because using netsuite TBA requires a callback URL that netsuite will redirect you to with the necessary credentials (access token and & token secret).

Comment: The underscore in realm fixed it for me. How did you figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this exact same issue. I have custom code written in Salesforce APEX that is connecting to NetSuite just fine. We also have a Workato integration that is connecting to NetSuite just fine.

No matter what I do in Postman, I get a 401 Invalid Login response. I'm losing my mind...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work for me. **Postman had a request header of "Connection"="keep-alive". Once I removed that it worked fine!** Wow.. I've been trying to get this to work for weeks, looking at it every few days for an hour or two. What a frustrating error message "Invalid Login".

Answer (score 0):

i found this article while troubleshooting this error with this exact error message and results in netsuite logs. For me, the role I was assigned to did not have permissions to Rest Web Services in Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

One other setting you need to change in Postman for NetSuite to work is 'Add auth data to' from 'Requests Body / Request URL' to 'Request Headers'